# Java code to search a path recursively and list all the directories starting with particular string

Tags: java, regex

Is there a java function to recursively search for a directory and list only those directories which start with particular string. For example:

```
drwxr-xr-x   - act actadmin          0 2018-07-11 18:14 /user/act/Forecast-Evaluation-Job-fdc8e1c8480947af8071e779f26121c5
drwxr-xr-x   - act actadmin          0 2018-07-11 14:25 /user/act/Forecast-Evaluation-Job-fffd3c15fcc34d5b97a1337810877e2f
-rw-r--r--   3 act actadmin       6918 2018-07-06 08:29 /user/act/bi_tool
```

In the above example I need to list the directories starting with "Forecast-Evaluation-Job" under the path "/user/act/".

Expected output should be:

```
drwxr-xr-x   - act actadmin          0 2018-07-11 18:14 /user/act/Forecast-Evaluation-Job-fdc8e1c8480947af8071e779f26121c5
drwxr-xr-x   - act actadmin          0 2018-07-11 14:25 /user/act/Forecast-Evaluation-Job-fffd3c15fcc34d5b97a1337810877e2f
```

Comment: do you mean [`(?=\/user\/act\/(Forecast-Evaluation.*))`](https://regex101.com/r/Nf2g3y/1) beside can you please show us the expected output?

Comment: I have edited my question and added the expected output

Comment: In this case you can use [`^.*\/user\/act\/Forecast-Evaluation.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/RWaV3X/1)

Comment: Thanks. But I need a java program to recursively search for the directories under "/user/act/" and list out only those directories which start with "Forecast-Evaluation-Job"

Comment: You have two answers you can take one

Comment: You should edit your question and mention that this is a recursive search, as that changes the possible answers.  (A single DirectoryStream or Files.list call is no longer sufficient.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java 8+ you can use [`Files.find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#find-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-):

```
Files.find(Paths.get("/user/act"), /*maxDepth*/1,
           (p, a) -> a.isDirectory() && p.getFileName().toString().startsWith("Forecast-Evaluation-Job"))
     .forEach(System.out::println); // replace this with whatever you want to do with it
```

If you need recursive searching, set `maxDepth` to a large number, e.g. `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

You can also use a [`PathMatcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/PathMatcher.html) which supports [`glob` and `regex` matching](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher-java.lang.String-):

```
Path dir = Paths.get("/user/act");
PathMatcher pathMatcher = dir.getFileSystem()
                             .getPathMatcher("glob:**/Forecast-Evaluation-Job*");
Files.find(dir, 1, (p, a) -> a.isDirectory() && pathMatcher.matches(p))
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Great answer, Andreas! I will remove mine :)

Comment: That worked for Java 8 :) Is there any substitute for Files.find() in Java 7?